# Configure JVM class loaders to only run encrypted JAR files

Tags: java, compilation, jvm, whitelist

I'm looking into methods of implementing and enforcing a white list of jar files, so that a jvm will only run certain jar's/applications

I was looking into encrypted class loaders that are used to load encrypted bytecode into the JVM. Would it be possible to change my JVM so that it only utilizes these loaders regardless of the Jar application?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  You would need to create a custom class loader which always used a password to access the JAR file.  BTW The class path is a white list already, do you want to have a secondary white list?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. However, it would be very, very difficult to do correctly, and would require significant engineering time and a very large amount of QA / verification to confirm that you'd succeeded.

The fact that you're asking this question may indicate that you may not have fully explored or grasped the problem you're trying to solve. Can you expand your question to indicate *what* you are trying to do, rather than just *how*?

Comment: Sure, the basic requirement is that the JRE/JVM will only execute a set list of JAR files / java applications. This project is only concerned with native java applications so java browser applets are considered out of scope.

Comment: @DGWelsh - So there is a user that has command-line (or similar) access to the machine and the ability to spin up a JVM, and you want to constrain which JAR files may appear on the classpath, effectively?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You need to edit/hook the native methods (defineClass0, defineClass1) inside the java.dll or the JVM_DefineClass inside the jvm.dll. Both of the source of these files can be found online (https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild).